# VHDL If Statement Syntax Error

Tags: syntax, syntax-error, vhdl

I have the following code:

```
process(value_counter, hex5_value)
    begin
        if(value_counter <= x"0F") then
            with value_counter select hex4 <=  --error on this line
            "0111111" when x"00", 
            "0000110" when x"01", 
            "1011011" when x"02", 
            "1001111" when x"03", 
            "1100110" when x"04", 
            "1101101" when x"05", 
            "1111101" when x"06", 
            "0000111" when x"07", 
            "1111111" when x"08", 
            "1101111" when x"09",
            "1110111" when x"0A", 
            "1111100" when x"0B",
            "0111001" when x"0C", 
            "1011110" when x"0D",
            "1111001" when x"0E", 
            "1110001" when x"0F";

            hex5<="0111111";
        elsif(value_counter > x"0F") then
            with value_counter mod 10 select hex4 <=
            "0111111" when x"00", 
            "0000110" when x"01", 
            "1011011" when x"02", 
            "1001111" when x"03", 
            "1100110" when x"04", 
            "1101101" when x"05", 
            "1111101" when x"06", 
            "0000111" when x"07", 
            "1111111" when x"08", 
            "1101111" when x"09",
            "1110111" when x"0A", 
            "1111100" when x"0B",
            "0111001" when x"0C", 
            "1011110" when x"0D",
            "1111001" when x"0E", 
            "1110001" when x"0F";

            with hex5_value select hex5 <=
            "0111111" when x"00", 
            "0000110" when x"01", 
            "1011011" when x"02", 
            "1001111" when x"03",
            "1100110" when x"04", 
            "1101101" when x"05", 
            "1111101" when x"06", 
            "0000111" when x"07", 
            "1111111" when x"08", 
            "1101111" when x"09",
            "1110111" when x"0A", 
            "1111100" when x"0B",
            "0111001" when x"0C", 
            "1011110" when x"0D",
            "1111001" when x"0E", 
            "1110001" when x"0F";
        end if;
end process;
```

but I am getting the following error on the indicated line when running it: `Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at xxx near text "with";  expecting "end", or "(", or an identifier ("with" is a reserved keyword), or a sequential statement`. Anyone know what's causing this, and how I can rewrite it legally and equivalently?

Comment: Did you really mean "mod 10" and not "mod 16"?

Comment: A selected signal assignment is supported in IEEE Std 1076-2008 See 10.5.4 Selected signal assignments. Presumably with a [mcve] your code would not produce a syntax error with a -2008 compliant tool (a tall ask from some FPGA vendors noting the error number).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "correct" answer is a CASE statement within a process or "with ... select" in the combinatorial region (i.e. outside a process).

But you would have much nicer VHDL if you created a constant array of 16 7-segment display values, and simply indexed the array :

```
subtype seven_seg is std_logic_vector(6 downto 0);

constant decode : array 0 to 15 of seven_seg := (
            "0111111", "0000110", "1011011", "1001111", 
            "1100110", "1101101", "1111101", "0000111", 
            "1111111", "1101111", "1110111", "1111100",
            "0111001", "1011110", "1111001", "1110001");

    process(value_counter, hex5_value)
        begin
            if value_counter <= x"0F" then
                hex4 <= decode(to_integer(value_counter(3 downto 0)));
                hex5 <= decode(0);
            -- elsif value_counter > x"0F" then  
            -- surely this "elsif" is unnecessary!
            else 
                hex4 <= decode(to_integer(value_counter(7 downto 4)));
                hex5 <= decode(to_integer(hex5_value(3 downto 0)));
            end if;
    end process;
```

Answer (score 0):

The signal assignment with 'with' is a concurrent statement.  So it's not valid inside a process.
A 'case' could do it.  But check the results of the timing analysis when the case becomes quiet long.

See [this link](http://www.iis.ee.ethz.ch/~zimmi/download/vhdl93_syntax.html#pred197) for more syntax information.